# Set multiple setTween Elements for scrolling in ScrollMagic

Tags: javascript, scrollmagic

my problem is that i use .setTween wrong. It uses just the second .setTween Element. In my case the #identity ID.

```
// init controller
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

// animations
var headerpic = TweenMax.to("#headerpic", 1, {opacity: 0.3});
var identity = TweenMax.from("#identity", 1, {opacity: 0});

// build scenes
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: "#pin1", 
  duration: "100%",
  triggerHook: 'onLeave'
})
  .setTween(headerpic)
  .setTween(identity)
  .setPin("#pin1")
  .addIndicators({name: "pin1"})
  .addTo(controller);
```

How do i have to set .setTween that one html-element is fading-out and the other is fading-in during the scrolling?

https://codepen.io/pauernet/pen/qBBaJYO